# How do I grab the two largest integers from a Javascript Array and return the value to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

I've written a solution to take a list of integers entered through a form. It works. It gives you the sum of the two largest integers and posts it in the DOM.
However, it's not very efficient for large arrays of say 1 million integers.

How can I improve this solution to be more efficient.

#### App.js

```js
 // This function reverses the order of the array and places the biggest numbers first
 function sortNumber(a, b) {
   return b - a;
 }


 // this function is used to ensure the user didn't enter any letters
 function getArray() {
   var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

   // This function takes the array, orders it, adds the sum of the two largest numbers and returns the value
   
   function sumOf(x) {
     
       // Sort the ary with the sortNumber function
       array.sort(sortNumber);
   
     // Then we add the two biggest numbers of the array and save it to the result variable.
     
       var result = array[0] + array[1];
     
       // Then we share the result with the user by updating the browser
       var myHeading = document.querySelector('h2');
       myHeading.textContent = "The sum of your two biggest numbers is: " + result;
       
     // Like a good student, it's important to show your work
       var showYourWork = document.querySelector('h3');
       showYourWork.textContent = array[0] + " + " + array[1] + " = " + result;
     }
     // This grabs the value of the input
   var arrayField = document.getElementById('arrayField').value;

   if (arrayField.match(alphaExp)) {
     
     // Fail if user enters letters
     var raiseError = document.querySelector('h5');
     raiseError.textContent = 'No not letters! We want numbers!!';
   } else {
     var array = JSON.parse("[" + arrayField + "]");
     if (arrayField.length < 2) {
       
       // If the user enters only 1 number, tell them to enter more!
       var raiseError = document.querySelector('h5');
       raiseError.textContent = 'Please enter atleast two numbers seperated by commas for us to add!'
     } else {
       
       // When the user enters a list of numbers, run the sumOf function.
       sumOf(arrayField);
       
       //Make the error go away
       var raiseError = document.querySelector('h5');
       raiseError.textContent = '';
     }
   }
 };

 // use an eventlistener for the event (This is where the magic happens)
 var subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
 subButton.addEventListener('click', getArray, false);
```

Comment: What does "not very efficient" mean exactly? The built-in sort function is a good efficient sort. You *might* be able to do better with a specially-built radix sort, depending on the nature of your input values.

Comment: I'm referring to processing power. My interpretation of the sort function is that it has to has to go back through the array every time it comes across an integer that doesn't immediately preceded the previous value and this seems rather inefficient if it has to sort a million integers.

Comment: No, sorting is an algorithmic domain that has been extensively studied for 60 or 70 years (and more). The `.sort()` method does have to do some work to sort your array, but be confident that it does it very efficiently. Now, if all you need is to extract the two top (or bottom) values, you can do that without sorting.

Comment: Do you actually need a sorted list, or is just determining the two biggest numbers sufficient? (Because completely sorting a million numbers just to find the two largest *sounds* like a pretty inefficient way to do it.)

Comment: Can you use TypedArray?

Comment: -nnnnn exactly, That's what I'm trying to understand

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to sort it, just search linearly for the two biggest ones:

EDIT: the code below should work now and is asymptotically faster than the OP's code. The OP does sorting first which can be done in O(n log n), assuming a random list. My code does a linear search through the list in `O(cn)` with `c = 2` (the two loops are not necessary but simple). The solution for `ceil(n log n) = 2n` with `n` a positive integer is 14, that is for every list longer than 14 entries the code below is faster. E.g.: for one million entries the relation is 13,815,511 to 2,000,000, more than six times faster. You can do the same thing in a single loop which halves the runtime (theoretically, but it is also a tiny bit faster because of the better locality).

```
function maxtwo_wrong(a){
    var b1 = -Infinity;
    var b2 = -Infinity;

    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > b1) {
            b1 = a[i];
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > b2 && a[i] < b1) {
            b2 = a[i];
        }
    } 
    return [b1,b2];
}
```

EDIT-2: The code above `maxtwo_wrong` seems not to fit the requirements, so I wrote another one `maxtwo_right`and put it below. Please, OP, tell me which one fulfills your requirements such that I can delete the wrong one.

EDIT-3: made it simpler and correct.

```
function maxtwo_right(a){
    var b1 = -Infinity;
    var b2 = -Infinity;

    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // If the current entry is bigger than variable b1
        // keep the old value in the variable b2 and set b1 to the
        // value of the current entry
        if (a[i] > b1) {
            b2 = b1;
            b1 = a[i];
        }
        // if the current entry equals b1 set the variable b2 to
        // the value of the current entry
        else if(a[i] === b1){
            b2 = a[i];
        }
    }
    // return the sum of the two variables as requested
    return b1 + b2;
}
```

Comment: "Not fully tested", why not?

Comment: Because I never run out of cheap excuses for code that does not work ;-) Well, actually: tested against a sorted array, but put that sorting first and `array.sort()` is in-place, so I was fooled by myself and have a hole in my foot now.

Comment: The only problem is when two biggest numbers are the same.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek the two biggest numbers are the same iff all numbers are the same. Or what do you mean? If the input is say `[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,8]` the output is `[8,7]`, do you think it should be `[8,8]` instead?

Comment: I suppose it should return the same as `array.sort(sortNumber); var result = array[0] + array[1];`.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Ah, understood now ;-) But it leads to the question (for the list as above): should it be `7 + 8 = 15` or `8 + 8 = 16`?

Comment: OP is the final judge, but for the behaviour be the same the result should be `16`.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek OP's long gone, I presume.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102867/discussion-between-antonin-lejsek-and-deamentiaemundi).

Comment: I like the logic of your second solution however when I implement it and I give it an array for example 1, 334, -34, 27, 232323, 23. It returns 73.  Here's the full source code https://github.com/ryanjamesdev/tempest

Comment: @RyanJames Yepp, had it wrong again, thanks for pointing that out! Although my old one didn't result in 73? The source-code you linked to has only your own sort-based algorithm in it. Edited the post to the correct code, please check if it works for you now. Otherwise I will rinse and repeat until it works to your satisfaction.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi, There seems to be a problem with edit 3, when I run the function, I get an error stating b1 is not defined. I've revamped it myself and it works until the point where it returns the value, it's returning a string as in '[1,2,3,4,5,6]' returns '56' and it doesn't recgonize negative values, can you help me with this last bit? It's on the mock2 branch of the github https://github.com/ryanjamesdev/tempest/tree/mock2

Answer (score 1):

I finally found some time to sit down and work this one out.
I was looking at the problem all wrong.

Here is my new solution

```
// This function adds the sum of the two largest integers of an array and returns the value
function topTwoInt(theArray) {
    var intArray = theArray;
    var highestInt = -Infinity;
    var secondHighestInt = -Infinity;
    var answer = 0;
    //Loop through the array
    for (var i=0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        //grab the biggest int and assign it to the highestInt variable;
        if (intArray[i] > highestInt) {
            secondHighestInt = highestInt;
            highestInt = intArray[i]; 
        }
        //If the next number is equal too highestInt or greater than secondHighestInt
        //Make that number become the new secondHighestInt
        else if(intArray[i] === highestInt || intArray[i] > secondHighestInt) {
            secondHighestInt = intArray[i];
        }
    }
    answer = highestInt + secondHighestInt;
    return answer;
};
```

This solution is largely inspired by @deamentiaemundi 
Thanks man.